# PyScripter Console launcher no arranca en Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, consola

¿Alguien sabría indicarme por qué al querer utilizar Console Launcher de PyScripter en Windows 10, esta no arranca?
Ni siquiera es que se abre la consola y se cierra, simplemente no hace nada, como si nunca la hubiese mandado a ejecutar.

Trabajo en mi laptop personal, tengo dos cuentas de usuario, la mía y una de administrador.
¿Tendría que hacer algún ajuste en la cuenta de administrador o en la mía?

Software utilizado:
PyScripter V3.8.3.0 x64
Windows 10

Muchas gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar en algunos sitios en Internet, pude solucionar el problema con el comando del sistema **SFC /SCANNOW**
Simplemente ejecuté desde la línea de comandos con privilegios de *ADMINISTRADOR* y después de que revisó todo el sistema la consola indicó que encontró errores y los solucionó, después al ejecutar *CONSOLE LAUNCHER* funcionó sin problemas.
Espero que a alguien más le sirva.

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solucion